# How to tell the Linker/Compiler to include seemingly "dead" code

Tags: c, pointers, arm

I have written a C program and I'm compiling with GCC (for an arm MCU).
I have a function that changes the address of void pointer to point to another void,and so on. 
The problem is that the Linker/Compiler think that the code is unused and discard it.
I have tried   **attribute**(( used )) but that didn't work.

The voids and code are in separate .h/.c file from the main.h/c but are included in the main.c

Code:

```
void q2_h(void (*ptr)(uint8_t), uint8_t a) {
    if (a == 3) {
        ptr = (void*) q3_h;
    } else {
        ptr = (void*) q22_h;
    }
}
```

Definition:

```
void q2_h(void (*ptr)(uint8_t), uint8_t a)__attribute__((used));
```

Input Pointer:

```
void (*ptr)(void*,uint8_t);
```

which is not completely right because the (uint8_t) is missing but I'm not sure about the syntax.

So if if you have any idea on how to sol

Comment: Why do you want dead code to get linked? Apart from being incorrect, this code does indeed do nothing. It's not "seemingly dead", it's truly dead. You change a local variable, not the function pointer at the caller side.

Comment: Why are you casting `q3_h` and `q22_h` to `void*`? Show the signatures of those functions.

Comment: If the compiler or linker "thinks" they are unused, chances are rather high that they are really unused. How would you use any function without your toolset knowing? You cannot call them and you cannot take the address of the function without them knowing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems:

- The code changes a local variable, not the function pointer in the calling code. So it is not "seemingly dead", it's truly dead. Instead of fiddling around with attributes, listen to what your compiler is trying to tell you.
- Always use `typedef` when dealing with function pointers, it would have made the bug more obvious.
- You cannot cast a function pointer to a void pointer or vice versa. `void*` is only a generic pointer type for *object pointers*. You shouldn't need to cast at all, or your code is attempting fishy invalid pointer conversions, which would be a bug.

Corrected code might look something like:

```
typedef void func_t (uint8_t);

void q2_h(func_t** ptr, uint8_t a) {
    if (a == 3) {
        *ptr = q3_h;
    } else {
        *ptr = q22_h;
    }
}
```